# Category with zero value required in group by result

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, null, zero

I'm using SQL SS with read-only permission. The data I'm using has 3 product types, but I need a result displaying a sum of transactions for 6 product types with zero values for the 3 not available:

Example result:

| Product Type | Total Transactions |
| --- | --- |
| Product Type 1 | £500,000 |
| Product Type 2 | £1,000,000 |
| Product Type 3 | £0.00 |
| Product Type 4 | £750,000 |
| Product Type 5 | £0.00 |
| Product Type 6 | £0.00 |

Product Type 3, 5 , and 6 do not exist in the table and therefore will always be zero but need to be in the result. All Product Types also need to be renamed for the criteria.

I have tried a Case expression with a group by product type which works for the 3 available product types, this is what I have that works:

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN Product Type = 'XYZ' AND Criteria1 = 'Y' THEN 'Product Type 1'
WHEN Product Type = 'ABC' AND Criteria1 = 'Y' THEN 'Product Type 2'
WHEN Product Type = 'DEF' AND Criteria1 = 'N' THEN 'Product Type 4'
END as "Product Type",

sum(Transactions) as "Total Transactions"

from ProductTable inner join TransactionTable on ProductCode = TransactionProductCode
where TransactionDate BETWEEN 'Date1' and 'Date2'

GROUP BY
CASE
WHEN Product Type = 'XYZ' AND Criteria1 = 'Y' THEN 'Product Type 1'
WHEN Product Type = 'ABC' AND Criteria1 = 'Y' THEN 'Product Type 2'
WHEN Product Type = 'DEF' AND Criteria1 = 'N' THEN 'Product Type 4'
END
```

Any advice to achieve the example result would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `left join` and move your date criteria to the join clause. You can also `coalesce` your amount when summing to return a 0 rather than null.

So it's something like this:

```
select 
 --case expression here,
 sum(coalesce(t.amount, 0)) as total_transactions
from products p 
left join transactions t 
  on p.productId = t.productId 
 and t.some_date between date1 and date2
group by --case expression
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it still isn’t working, what do you suggest I use (I’m assuming in the case expression) to get Product Type 3, 5 & 6 in the result? Many thanks!